# Interaction between SASnRdisplay and Tufte book class

Tags: listings, tufte, sasnrdisplay

SASnRdisplay is a package to display SAS and R code and results. It appears to have some bad interaction with the Tufte book class. The code below produces very odd text (letters with a variety of accent marks) instead of the single quotes around the *'s that indicate significance.

If I remove the quotes around the accent marks, it runs fine, but I will have a lot of these tables and removing them by hand would be tiresome and error prone.

If I run the same code with an article documentclass, it runs fine, even with the quotes.

Suggestions for either a) Making this run properly as is or b) Automating the removal of the 's are welcome.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book} % Use the tufte-book class which in turn uses the tufte-common class
\usepackage{listings} % For display code listings
\usepackage[english]{SASnRdisplay}
%\usepackage{microtype} % Improves character and word spacing

\begin{document}


      \begin{Routput}
      Call: lm(formula = y ~ x)

       Residuals:
            Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max
       -28.8626  -6.1401   0.0236   5.8645  29.8774

       Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
       (Intercept)   0.3715     1.0498   0.354  0.72416
       x             2.7392     1.0378   2.639  0.00966 **
       ---
       Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

       Residual standard error: 10.37 on 98 degrees of freedom
       Multiple R-squared:  0.06637,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.05685
       F-statistic: 6.967 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.009661
       \end{Routput}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Those quotes are they ascii or some unicode char?

Comment: As expected you are using quotes (utf8) that are generally not supported in listings (which `SASnRdisplay` is build on). You can probably define them using listings literals. Will test later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SASnRdisplay` is build upon the `listings` package. That package can only handle single byte input, thus not UTF8 (which is 2 byte).

There are some tricks one can use if you only need to support a few non-ascii chars, namely the `literate` option, where you specify the UTF8 input, and the specific TeX output for that char.

In this case it is the utf8 quotes that are the problem.

This works:

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book} % Use the tufte-book class which in turn uses the tufte-common class
\usepackage{listings} % For display code listings
\usepackage[english]{SASnRdisplay}
%\usepackage{microtype} % Improves character and word spacing


\lstdefinestyle{r-output-user}{
   literate={‘}{{`}}1
            {’}{{'}}1
}


\begin{document}

      \begin{Routput}
      Call: lm(formula = y ~ x)

       Residuals:
            Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max
       -28.8626  -6.1401   0.0236   5.8645  29.8774

       Coefficients:
                   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
       (Intercept)   0.3715     1.0498   0.354  0.72416
       x             2.7392     1.0378   2.639  0.00966 **
       ---
       Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

       Residual standard error: 10.37 on 98 degrees of freedom
       Multiple R-squared:  0.06637,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.05685
       F-statistic: 6.967 on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: 0.009661
       \end{Routput}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

At least for R one alternative could be use `knitr`. Bonus: you do not need to mess with the results, only with the source:

```
\documentclass[nobib]{tufte-book}
\begin{document}
{\centering R oputput\par\small
<<echo=F,comment=NA, background="#EEFFFF" >>=
x <- rnorm(100,6,9)
y <- rnorm(100,3,1)
summary(lm(x~y))
@
}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage[english]{SASnRdisplay}

\begin{document}

\begin{Routput}
0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
\end{Routput}

\end{document}
```

Leads to on my system (compiled with LuaTeX):

[image]

1. **What does your output look like?**
2. **Do you use `\usepackage[???]{inputenc}` in your real code?**

Comment: 1. Mine has a whole bunch of accented characters instead of the quotation marks. 2. No, I don't.